# Mysterious Self-Originating File with the one-charcter name ":" (colon)

Tags: terminal, file

There's a file in my /users/myName that has appeared out of nowhere. It's named ":" in Terminal, "/" in Finder. It may be deleted (either drag and drop to trash or rm in Terminal) but will reappear the next time Terminal is closed--if already closed, one must open and then quit the terminal before it will appear. The file contains no data (0 kb).

I hope this isn't so mysterious to someone. Any insight would be most appreciated.

Comment: What's in the file? Use `cat` in Terminal. Check your `.bashrc`, or `bash_profile` maybe it creates them. Or the command Terminal runs when you login, from the preferences.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is indeed empty: `cat` returns nothing. I checked bash_profile and preferences and nothing seems to be awry.

Comment: Rechecking, it turns out the problem did lie in `bash_profile`. Still working it out, but I've isolated it to a corrupted `PYTHONPATH` export. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You wanna write an answer and accept it, or should I? Other may have the same problem, and might not look in the comments.